# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS streaming digitizing

Tags: qgis, digitizing, vertices

I am trying to digitize in QGIS 3.14, and I  have not been able to find an equivalent to the ArcGIS streaming tool. I was taught to digitize where [(you trace the feature with your mouse and nodes are added automatically at a given interval)](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008086). Otherwise you get weird blocky lines unless you zoom very close.

Not sure if I am looking for the right terminology, but can't seem to find the right tool in QGIS.

This is my current advanced digitizing toolbar
[image: This is my current advanced digitizing toolbar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable ["Advanced Digitizing Toolbar"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#advanced-digitizing) and you can find ["Stream Digitizing"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#straight-curve-and-stream-digitizing):

[image]

Comment: Just press `R` to activate/deactivate stream digitizing mode.